# Boost Spirit X3 Skip Parser Implementation?

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit-x3

For the current grammar I am parsing with X3, whitespace and Perl-style comments are ignored.

It seems to me that a skip parser in X3 is just a normal parser, and whatever input it consumes is considered "skipped." I came up with this:

```
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
auto const blank_comment = 
   x3::blank | x3::lexeme[ '#' >> *(x3::char_ - x3::eol) >> x3::eol ];
```

On parsing a very basic input (a couple comment lines and one quoted string line), this seems to work well. ([Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7e58ddcb568593b))

However, as I can't find any documentation on the matter and the details of current skip parsers are tucked away in an intricate system of templates, I was hoping for some input.

1. Is this the proper way of defining a "skip parser"? Is there a standard method?
2. Are there performance concerns with an implementation like this? How would it be improved?

I previously searched SO for the details, and found an answer using Qi ([Custom Skip Parser with Boost::Spirit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8521314/custom-skip-parser-with-boostspirit)). As I never learned Qi, much of the details are hard to follow. The method I described above seems more intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah that's fine.

The skipper seems pretty optimal. You could optimize the `quoted_string` rule by reordering and using character set negation (`operator~`):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1845d92a66d28aa1)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
    auto const quoted_string = x3::lexeme [ '"' >>  *('\\' >> x3::char_ | ~x3::char_("\"\n")) >> '"' ];
    auto const space_comment = x3::space | x3::lexeme[ '#' >> *(x3::char_ - x3::eol) >> x3::eol];
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string result, s1 = "# foo\n\n#bar\n   \t\"This is a simple string, containing \\\"escaped quotes\\\"\"";

    phrase_parse(s1.begin(), s1.end(), parser::quoted_string, parser::space_comment, result);

    std::cout << "Original: `" << s1 << "`\nResult: `" << result << "`\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Original: `# foo

#bar
    "This is a simple string, containing \"escaped quotes\""`
Result: `This is a simple string, containing "escaped quotes"`
```

Comment: Thanks for the optimization tip and answer.

Comment: Maybe for `space_comment` it is better to use [seek directive](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/repository/doc/html/spirit_repository/qi_components/directives/seek.html)?

Comment: @Orient I dint recommend depending on unsupported contributor chide fir something that looks a lot like premature optimization.

Comment: ok. Phones are hard to use. "I don't recommend depending on unsupported contributor code for" ...

Comment: Does repository contain bad quality code? I propose it above not for optimization sake, but for readability reasons.

Comment: It's not bad code. It's just not supported. The docs are pretty clear about this. I strongly suspect it's not better in any way here.

Comment: BTW [seek directive](https://github.com/boostorg/spirit/blob/develop/include/boost/spirit/home/x3/directive/seek.hpp) is a part of main *Spirit X3* code. I just linked the relevant documentation from *Spirit V2* repository.